# SQL Server Web Edtion Failover Cluster

Tags: sql-server-2008, failover, failovercluster, windows

Is it possible to run an SQL Server Web edition in a Windows 2008 R2 Failover Environment?

I want to host a Website with backend database but keep it failsave with a failover cluster (install it on two nodes and failover if one node fails).

Answer (score 0):

Only Standard and Enterprise editions support clustering, and Standard only 2 nodes at that. Have a look at this matrix: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(SQL.100).aspx

Comment: is there a way to do that manually? Like stopping services etc. Clustering something etc.?

Comment: You could simulate it with log shipping, where the fail over would be manual, and still you would lose the unshipped part of work (typically up to 15 minutes).